# Django: Multiply inside query set

Tags: python, django

I wonder if the way I calculate `quantity * price_gross`is the right way to do it. Or is there a better way to multiply these values inside the `Ticket.objects.` query set?

```
event = Event.objects.get(pk=4)

test = Ticket.objects.filter(event=event).values('quantity', 'price_gross')
result = 0
for x in test:
    result += x['quantity']*x['price_gross']

print(result)
```

Updated:

```
Ticket.objects.filter(
    event__organizer__in=self.organizers,
    event__status=EventStatus.LIVE,
).values('event__pk', 'pk')
.order_by('event__pk')
.annotate(
    total_gross=F('quantity') * F('price_gross'),
)
.aggregate(Sum('total_gross'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There's indeed a way of doing that and it's by using [Query Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)

```py
test = Ticket.objects.filter(event=event).annotate(total=F('quantity') * F('price_gross'))
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. However, I had to use annotate instead of filter. `test = Ticket.objects.filter(event=event).values('quantity', 'price_gross').annotate(total=F('quantity') * F('price_gross'))`

Comment: Nice that it worked and I got it why you used `annotate`. I'm gonna correct my answer then

Answer (score 1):

You can go one further and also do the summing in the database (untested! but should more or less work):

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

result = (
    Ticket.objects.filter(event=event)
    .values('quantity', 'price_gross')
    .annotate(total=F('quantity') * F('price_gross'))
    .aggregate(Sum('total'))
)
```

Comment: That's even better! Saved me another for loop. Thank you!

Comment: I only realized one problem with that. My current query is above under UPDATED. Is it possible to only build the Sum per `event__pk`. Currently, it's building the sum from all events together.